# Check if Workbook variable has been set

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub with an optional workbook argument. I want an `If` to check whether that variable was passed, and if not set the variable to the active worksheet.

```
Sub SaveWorkbook(NewPathName As String, Optional Workbook As Workbook)
    'This is very simplified, the real thing has various other parameters

    If IsNull(Workbook) Then Set Workbook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Then loads more stuff
End Sub
```

Things I have tried include:

`IsNull(Workbook)`
`IsEmpty(Workbook)`
`Workbook = Nothing`

None trigger the If statement so the code attempts to continue with `Workbook` set to Empty, and then hits errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the word "Workbook" as the variable name. Try it like this:

```
Sub SaveWorkbook(NewPathName As String, Optional wb As Workbook)

  If wb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "workbook not set"
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  End If

  MsgBox wb.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Should be isMissing for optional Parameters un vba

Comment: IsMissing would work, if the seond argument would be defined as `Optional wb as Variant`. Then you could use the current workbook, if the `sub SaveWorkbook` was called without the second option. As answered below by @MG92.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA the isMissing function only works, if you declare the parameter as `Variant`. See in the [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ismissing-function)

This should work:

```vb
Sub SaveWorkbook(NewPathName As String, Optional Workbook As Variant)
    'This is very simplified, the real thing has various other parameters

    If isMissing(Workbook) Then Set Workbook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Then loads more stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: Or you can just check to see if the optional workbook argument is nothing.

Comment: While this is a true statement, the OP wants to pass in a Workbook not a Variant.  Plus, the answer from @braX works well.

Comment: @braX With objects checking for `Nothing` works fine, if you have an optional `String` however checking for `Nothing` will give you an error. Here you would have to check for `If opt_string <> "" Then`. `IsMissing` takes care for all `Types`. But I guess it comes down to preference.

Comment: And since the OP is not passing an optional `String` argument, it is better to check for `Nothing` in this case.

Comment: @braX but you can't tell apart arg not passed and arg set to nothing that way if you need to know that (of course OP will be fine with check for nothing even he asks for a check if passed or not).

Comment: @braX I just wanted to give a different approach. I saw you tried using `isMissing` from your comment and I had the same issue a while back and thought to give some insight.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher True, but I have never needed to know if a parameter wasn't passed.  I suppose there may be a use case for this situation, but I can't think of one.

Comment: What I dont like about this solution is that you cannot use Intellisense while coding in the routine if it is defined as a `Variant`.